# Under ARC, my code become slow, is this normal?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

My app runs slow after I spend 2 days changing it to work with ARC.

Dose I make some mistake to make it slow?
Or ARC is a little slow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s practically impossible to feel a difference after doing a correct conversion to ARC. Remember that ARC is not a garbage collector, it’s almost like if the compiler placed the manual memory management calls into the source code for you (= no extra runtime overhead).

Are you sure about the performance difference? Can you measure it against the older code revison? Did you profile the new code in Instruments for memory leaks? Why did it take two days to convert the code, did the automatic Xcode conversion not work for you? Why?

Comment: I am not very familiar with the ARC and automatic Xcode conversion is very ugly because Code is full of duplication declaration(both property and ivar in interface) and Many IBOutlet are retain property. So it spend two days...

Comment: In a navController, When I want to push into another view, should I end the network request in the original viewController's viewWillDisappear ?

Comment: The automatic conversion works fine. I’m not sure what you mean by the duplicated declarations – surely they are not added during the automatic conversion? IMO the best way to convert your code to ARC is to run the automatic conversion and return to check problematic cases by hand. Otherwise it’s hard to give advice without you diagnosing the problem better.

Comment: Problem solved. My problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11449734/under-arc-keep-getting-exc-bad-access-after-using-arc-beacause-of-using-block#comment15125577_11449734