# Under ARC, keep getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS after using ARC, because of using Block?

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

Issue:
I keep getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS. And after I open NSZombieEnabled, I saw this [FeatureCommentListViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7c1dc30

1. Before I changed my project to ARC, there is no such error, but after I changed to ARC, this error appeared.
2. I declare a ViewController in a Block and push it into navigation Controller. Will this reason case it's lifetime shorter?

   UIBlockButton is from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11449194/how-to-make-uiblockbutton-suit-with-arc/11449394#11449394)

   ```
   UIBlockButton *lbGood3 = [[UIBlockButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, First_Button_Width, [self getGoodRow2Height:productDetail]) ];
   [lbGood3 handleControlEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside withBlock:^ { 
   NSLog(@"%@", Label.text); 

   ProductDetail *productDetail = [productDetailDict objectForKey:@"product"];
   NSString *dp_id = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@",productDetail.url_crc,productDetail.site_id];


   FeatureCommentListViewController *cmtListController = [[FeatureCommentListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FeatureCommentListViewController" bundle:nil];
   cmtListController.title = Label.text;
   cmtListController.isReviewed=isReviewed;
   cmtListController.productDetail=productDetail;
   cmtListController.dp_id=dp_id;
   cmtListController.feature_name = @"&feature_good_id=2";

   [self.navigationController pushViewController:cmtListController animated:YES];

   }];
   ```

Should I declare the controller as a member of this viewController or just declare out of the block?

Comment: where did you get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Comment: Im wondering why push a view controller in a block but not in the main thread? Isn't it important to give a quick response to the touch action? ps. If you declare the vc out of the block you can add __block in front of it as mentioned by Hermann Klecker.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace? Does the EXC_BAD_ACCESS occur inside the block, or after the controller is pushed? Your navigation controller should retain `cmtListController` when you push it, and ARC should add a `[cmtListController release]` at the end of the block, after the last access of `cmtListController`.

Comment: @ChristopherPickslay actually no. Because the EXC_BAC_ACCESS happened in a callback function of a network request. But I can get the released object's class (FeatureCommentListViewController). I solved this by alloc the FeatureCommentListViewController in the viewDidLoad function and use it in block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by alloc the FeatureCommentListViewController in the viewDidLoad function and use it in block.

Answer (score -2):

**1st**. Im wondering why do you push a view controller in a block but not in the main thread? Isn't it important to give a quick response to the touch action?

**2nd**.`[self.navigationController pushViewController:cmtListController animated:YES];` is in your block. Whenever you left the current `navigationController` what will the `self.navigationController` represent?

**3rd**. If you declare the `viewController` out of the block you can add `__block` in front of it as mentioned by Hermann Klecker.

Comment: All of this is irrelevant--1) the block is executed on the main thread (see his linked post), 2) self is a retained reference to the current view controller. how would it have a different nav controller while this button is displayed?, and 3) using `__block` would allow him to modify a pointer defined outside the block, but that shouldn't be necessary--he's creating a new child controller when a button is tapped.

Comment: @ChristopherPickslay Thanks for you correction. But if the block is perform on the main thread, why do we use block here?

Comment: I think the point of his `UIBlockButton` is that you can define the button's action in-place, rather than pointing it to a target/action. That's great when you have to create a lot of dynamic buttons. In his case, he's configuring the controller with data specific to the cell the button is in. That's possible with target/action, but it takes some gymnastics.